# ASP.NET System.Web.UI.Page Cache Key Dependencies, How to?

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache, cache-control

How do I setup caching for a Page in ASP.NET and give it a cache key dependency?  I am familiar how to do this with a UserControl, I set a Partial Caching attribute and then set

```
this.CachePolicy = new CacheDependency(..)
```

How would I do this for a Page?  It does not have a CachePolicy object, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      Response.AddCacheItemDependency("Pages");
}

where "Pages" is the cache key dependency.